# Tensorflow in jupyter: variable already exists

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Here is partial neural network code from a "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow" example that works as intended:

```
with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = fully_connected(X, n_hidden1, activation_fn=leaky_relu, scope="hidden1")
    hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1, n_hidden2, activation_fn=leaky_relu, scope="hidden2")
    logits = fully_connected(hidden3, n_outputs, activation_fn=None, scope="outputs")
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,
                                                          logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
```

However, if I simply rerun the Jupyter cell, I get the following error. This means I can't make changes like adding another hidden layer.

```
ValueError: Variable hidden1/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

I tried tf.reset_default_graph(), but only resetting the entire Jupyter notebook fixes this. What is the best fix for this error so that I can make changes to the neural network?

Comment: Using tf.reset_default_graph() works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply setting reuse=True for each layer?
reuse: Boolean, whether to reuse the weights of a previous layer by the same name.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense

Seems like a valid option to me.